# Restore Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 to clean state easily

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

Some programs that we have are installed on Windows 10 machines, while others are running on Windows Server 2016. To have an easy way of testing our installers, I would like to be able to restore the state of the machine to how it was before running the installers. As some of the installers might install 3rd party drivers, only uninstalling our software would not be enough. Keeping track of and uninstalling all 3rd party drivers will probably be hard to do as well.

Is there a way of saving a version of Windows and then to easily restore that version?

Answer (score 2):

If possible try to virtualise these systems, that way you can snapshot the whole VMs, make your changes, run your tests and then revert back to the snapshot - I see this kind of thing happening all the time, it works great but doesn't take into account some situations such as physical hardware requirements - but if this isn't an issue then give it a try.

Comment: That is definitely something that we can try. I have had some troubles with both virtual machines and with docker containers when it comes to installing some drivers and testing some software though. For example, running QTest in docker containers were not possible, as the windows core image did not contain some obscure DLL that was needed. For virtual machines using Hyper-V, I think that there might be some trouble with testing the drivers that we have. The best would be to not have to work around these kinds of problems, but to have the exact same machine that we have in production.